# Is it possible for function to have access to whole scope of wherever it gets called from

Tags: javascript, node.js

In nodejs router, I'm doing plenty of stuff with sessions. In Ruby on Rails I could have taken it out into its own class like `session_helper` then in route controller I'd only say something like this `include sessions_helper` then all of the sudden it'd have access to all data currently available in class then i could do `session.renew`

Right now only way I see is create a function, then pass req & res as parameter to it in router.

Is there a way to simply import the class and then start using it's methods, which requires them to have access to this scope.

Answer (score 0):

In nodejs with the usual session functionality, the session for the current request will be in `req.session`.  Since all code that operates on a request originates from the request handler that has access to the `req` object, you can simply pass along either `req` or `req.session` to any code that wants to operate on the session belonging to the current request.  That is how things are typically done in nodejs.

It is not clear exactly what you mean by "import the class and then start using its methods).  If you want to create a class that operates on a session, you can simply create some middleware such as:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    req.mySessionObject = new mySession(req.session);
    next();
});
```

And then, `req.mySessionObject` will be your session object (initialized with the appropriate session for the current request) in all your requests and you can simply access `req.mySessionObject` anywhere and any methods you create on that object.  You will still have to pass `req` or `req.mySessionObject` to any function that wants to use your session object or declare the function within the scope of your route handler and then you can directly access the `req` object at any time.

If this doesn't cover what you were trying to describe, then please show us a code example for what you want to be able to do.

Comment: right now i am doing something like this: `session.validateCode(...arguments);` then in there i've access to res, req, next etc. But in Rails, I could include a utility class, and it'd add methods to the class which then i could call from my methods

Comment: @MuhammadUmer - I do not understand what you're trying to do.  Forget about rails for now (I don't know rails so it doesn't help me at all).  Please just describe what you're trying to accomplish (not how you're trying to accomplish it).  I've described how you could have your own session methods if you want.  Not sure what else you want.